# CSS Stock Ticker Fix

Tags: css

I finally found a stock ticker that works in all browsers. Just looking to do a few more hacks to make it look nicer:

1)Make font same size as rest of the page
2)Get rid of the "current stock values" black bar
3)Remove the light grey behind the stock symbol

Thanks so much for your help

Here is the page
http://petrowest.squarespace.com/home/

Comment: And we should help you do your job... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a module rather than putting the code directly into the website, you'll have to hack around it:

```
.standard[background-color="#000000"] { display: none; }
.standard { font-size: 14px; /* put in size here */ background:white; /* eliminate grey background}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source of the petrowest site that you linked. It looks like petrowest is using this stock ticker module:

http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/111070972621517437361/mini-stocks-gadget.xml

Once you embed the module into your website, you should be able to host the xml file locally and then edit the definition of the stock ticker.

If you view the source code of the petrowest page, you'll see this line:

`<div class="stock-ticker"><script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/111070972621517437361/mini-stocks-gadget.xml&amp;up_stocks=PRW.TO&amp;synd=open&amp;w=200&amp;h=50&amp;title=&amp;output=js"></script></div>`

Then, if you click on the embedded url, `http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/111070972621517437361/mini-stocks-gadget.xml`, you'll see a function definition that has an inline css definition. If you save mini-stocks-gadget.xml to your server, you should be able to experiment with the css portion of the function to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Ok sorry everyone, I have not been able to get it to work.This is what I have for my CSS .standard {background-color: #FFF;} { display: none !important; }
.standard { font-size: 14px !important; background-color: #FFF;} Here is the link to the page again http://petrowest.squarespace.com/home/